# how to get the return value from my doInBackground task?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm new on android studio and I'm trying to do an AsyncTask for my Network operation.

The problem is to get the return variable from it to be able to set the image in the imageview. `imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(var)`

```
public class ZoomActivity  extends Activity {


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url2 = intent.getStringExtra("image");


        ImageView imgDisplay;
        Button btnClose;


        imgDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);


        //Bitmap var = return of doInBackground??????????
        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(var);


        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ZoomActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });


    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... Params) {
            String myString = Params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(URL???); //how to pass url2 var here?
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                return myBitmap; ??????????
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

any examples?

Comment: What does that url call returns? Does it return image url?

Comment: in doInBackground? I need to pass the url2 var to this function (this var is from intent with an url) so I can transform this in a bitmap and set my imageview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, declare this asynctask class:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String myString = Params[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myString);
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Your zoomActivity changes to:

```
public class ZoomActivity  extends Activity {
ImageView imgDisplay;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url2 = intent.getStringExtra("image");



    Button btnClose;


    imgDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);


    //call asynctask
    new MyTask().execute(url2);


    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ZoomActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });


}
```

hope this works

Comment: change the code for getting bitmap from url if that code doesnt work. `URL url = new URL(myString);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;`

Comment: I think your are using asynctask to load image from url in background. Instead of that u can use Picasso library. add `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` in you app gradle. then `Picasso.with(this).load(url2).into(imgDisplay);` You no need to convert image into bitmap. Also by using this you can scale ur image , add placeholder etc. read http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 2):

When your doInBackground returns an object, it goes to the method [onPostExecute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) as an input parameter, and that method executes in the UI thread and not a parallel thread, so you can set the imag

Answer (score 1):

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
This this for reference. 
Change you MyTask to

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, BitMap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... Params) {
        String myString = Params[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL???); //how to pass url2 var here?
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap; ??????????
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
             //set the Image here.
imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(result);
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should let the AsyncTask return a Bitmap instead of a String

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... Params) {
        String myString = Params[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myString); //how to pass url2 var here?
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //set your bitmap here to your imgDisplay
    }

}
```

Then you start the task with

```
new MyTask().execute(/* urlString*/)
```

Comment: thank you very much! inside void onPostExecute I tried to add: `imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(result);` but cannot resolve symbol imgDisplay... do I need a context?

Comment: you need to declare imgDisplay in the class, instead of in the method.